# Implement AppstoreConnect API POST Request subscriptionPromotionalOffers

Tags: php, ios, app-store-connect-api

Unfortunately, the TSI Team is not willing to help me. Maybe someone here is able to help. :)

I'm trying to create a subscriptionPromotionalOffer for the AppstoreConnect API in PHP.

I'm using the latest app_store_connect_api_2.3_openapi.json and I generated the PHP API with openapi-generator-cli-6.6.0.

API Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_promotional_offer

Request url: https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptionPromotionalOffers

I'm sending the following payload:

`{ "data":{ "type":"subscriptionPromotionalOffers", "attributes":{ "name":"TEST_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME", "offerCode":"TEST_SUBSCRIPTION_CODE", "duration":"ONE_YEAR", "offerMode":"PAY_UP_FRONT", "numberOfPeriods":1 }, "relationships":{ "subscription":{ "data":{ "type":"subscriptions", "id":"1575201034" } }, "prices":{ "data":[ { "type":"subscriptionPromotionalOfferPrices", "id":"eyJzIjoiMTU3NTIwMTAzNCIsInQiOiJVU0EiLCJwIjoiMTAyMTIifQ" } ] } } } }`

I'm getting the following error:

`409 Conflict response: { "errors":[ { "id":"79b54fc7-0e8d-4228-99ab-4937551b5303", "status":"409", "code":"ENTITY_ERROR.RELATIONSHIP.INVALID", "title":"The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value", "detail":"Missing a required include subscriptionPricePoint", "source":{ "pointer":"/data/relationships/prices" } } ] }`

I think the error is a wrong id for subscriptionPromotionalOfferPrices which I don't understand.

I`m saving all ids for all prices for all pricePoints for all subscriptions in my local db and try to use those ids for the subscriptionPromotionalOfferPrices. I also tried to provide the id for each country. If I do this, I get the same error for each id for each country. The provided id eyJzIjoiMTU3NTIwMTAzNCIsInQiOiJVU0EiLCJwIjoiMTAyMTIifQ references to 26.99$ price for the USA subscriptionPricePoint.

Can someone provide me a working example for this request?

If the id is wrong, can someone tell me: How to query the right ids for each country for each subscription?

I already tried [https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptionPromotionalOffers/{id}/prices](https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptionPromotionalOffers/%7Bid%7D/prices) and [https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptionPromotionalOffers/{id}](https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/subscriptionPromotionalOffers/%7Bid%7D)

to fetch information for an existing Promotional Offer, but I was not able to fetch meaningful data from that endpoints.

I'm able to modify all prices for an existing subscription via API, so I'm sure the IDs I use are valid subscriptionPricePoint ids for each country.